# Porting TinyXml2 code to C# XmlDocument to replace text values in elements

Tags: c#, xmldocument

Using **TinyXml2** I can change the text value of all elements like this:

```
void CAssignHistoryDlg::UpdateNameAssignHistXML(tinyxml2::XMLElement* pElement, CString strExistingName, CString strReplacementName)
{
    TIXMLASSERT(pElement);

    USES_CONVERSION;

    if (pElement != NULL)
    {
        CString strText(CA2CT(pElement->GetText(), CP_UTF8));
        if (strText.CollateNoCase(strExistingName) == 0)
            pElement->SetText(CT2CA(strReplacementName, CP_UTF8));
    }

    for (tinyxml2::XMLElement* pChildElement = pElement->FirstChildElement(); pChildElement != NULL; pChildElement = pChildElement->NextSiblingElement()) {
        UpdateNameAssignHistXML(pChildElement, strExistingName, strReplacementName);
    }
}
```

But if I am using C# and a `XmlDocument` instead, how do I go about the same thing? I simply want to read the XML file, locate any elements where the text value is **AAA** and replace it with **BBB** and then save it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this document for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var doc =
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("first", "old"),
        new XElement("Second",
            new XElement("Third", "old")
        )
    );

string oldValue = "old";
string newValue = "new";

ReplaceValue(doc, oldValue, newValue);
```

And the method definition is like:

```
public void ReplaceValue(XElement element, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    if (element.HasElements)
    {
        foreach (var elem in element.Descendants())
        {
            ReplaceValue(elem, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }
    else if (element.Value == oldValue)
    {
        element.Value = newValue;
    }
}
```

To read a file into XElement, use `XElement.Load("C:\\file.xml")`, and for saving use `XElement.Save("C:\\file.xml")`.

Comment: Thank you. So, how do we read a XML file in from the PC into this `XElement` ? And then after the operation save it? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. For your first `if(doc.Value == oldValue)`, what exactly is it checking? The root node?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yeah, if the root is actually a text element containing the old value, and has no children. I thought that what your first `if` is about in the original question. Pardon me if I read it wrong, as I have basic understanding of C++.

Comment: Can I just ask you a couple of side questions? 1. What is the benefit of declaring `doc` as a `var` object? 2. Is there any benefit in wrapping a single line `if` clause content with curly braces?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle 1. By using var you are telling the compiler to figure out the type from the right hand side object, instead of you typing it. It is still statically typed, and so if the right hand side is string, then the variable becomes string, and if you try to store `int` for example, it will refuse. 2 It is just a styling I like, you can use a shorthand form.

Comment: My original code uses recursion so that it can go to any depth in the XML file. When I try your code it is not detected names nested deeper.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I did not realize that. I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks! So, looking at your new recursive method, an element either has a value or a set of sub elements. It can't have both. Great learning. Thanks.